# Typescript - Why are global symbols not working properly?

Tags: typescript, symbols

I have two files. In the first one, I created a type and added there `[id]` prop, which refers to the global symbol. In the second one, I would like to import that type and do some manipulation with the type (e.g., filter some `Array<Data>` via `[id]`; create some `data: Data`, etc.), but I got an Error.

```
// file1
export const id = Symbol.for("id");

export type Data = {
  [id]: string;
  name: string;
  age: number;
  active: boolean;
};
```

```
// file2
import {Data, id} from './file1';

const ref = Symbol.for('id');

const data: Data = {
  [ref]: '1234567890', // got an Error. see below
  // TS2322: Type '{ [id]: string; name: string; age: number; active: true; }' is not assignable to type 'Data'.   Object literal may only specify known properties, and '[id]' does not exist in type 'Data'.
  name: 'John',
  age: 32,
  active: true
}

console.log(ref === id); // actual result is equal to true, but Typescript shows an Error
// TS2367: This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'typeof ref' and 'typeof import("~/file1").id' have no overlap.
```

It looks like the Typescript does not work properly with global symbols, created via `Symbol.for('id')`.
Any suggestions on this, guys?